# Flutter - Gradle task assembleDebug failed

Tags: flutter, dart

When you run flutter run, such an error is displayed, when checking flutter doctor no error, what is the reason?

[image]

Comment: Post your error log not screenshot.

Comment: this is a problem with the gradle file being corrupt, first of all go to this gradle file in your flutter project, root/android/build.gradle file and find the gradle version that your app uses it will be something like this ` classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'``. then, go to this path C:Users\YOUR_USER\.gradle\wrapper\dists and delete the gradle folder coressponding to the gradle version. for example for me, ill have to delete the folder named gradle-3.5.0. for you it will be the folder with the same version as  the version inside the `android/build.gradle`

Comment: after that, re-run flutter run , it should download the gradle file successfully

Comment: hey.. you got the solution or still facing this in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue for my project earlier and found the solution as below.
I have changed the Gradle wrapper properties distribution URL version to: `5.5.1-all` which was available in my system.
Due to some reason, the android studio was fetching the latest version which was not in my system.
**Problem:**
Zip error occurs while compiler tries to wrap code with Gradle wrapper properties.
If the required files are missing or not properly available after downloading, this error occurs.
**Solutions:**
1) Redownload the Gradle which you are using currently.
2) Change the version of Gradle wrapper property version available in your system.